# How to pass a value from one page to another in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios

I am using a `UIPageView` Controller in my simple iOS app. I want to use 4 different page in my app which display different content.

I want to pass a value from one page to the another page. Please suggest me how I can do that in a straightforward way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code Hiren kanetiya. Did you try anything?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanna pass a value from view1 to view2, so create an object of view2 in your `segue` method of view1, and set the value of that variable in view2 in this segue.

Make sure the variable is `public` in view2